# Non Singular matrix contained in a Singular one

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to prove that a matrix $V_{n\times p}\in \mathrm{R}$ with orthonormal columns contains at least one $p\times p$ non singular matrix?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $p\le n$.

The dimensions of the row space and the column space of a real matrix agree. As orthonormal vectors the columns are independent, so the column space has dimension $p$. Therefore the row space must be all of $\Bbb{R}^p$. We can then find a set of $p$ linearly independent rows by the simple process of going thru the row vectors one by one and including/rejecting a row according to whether it is a linear combination of the previously included rows. As the rows span all of $\Bbb{R}^p$ the process ends with a selection of $p$ linearly independent rows.

Those selected row vectors the clearly form a non-singular $p\times p$ matrix.

Comment: You also need to recall that a spanning set of a space also contains a basis.

Comment: So given the fact that the columns are independent ($p \le n$), means that there are $p$ independent rows. These rows create the row space and finally we may have a $p \times p$ non singular sub matrix. Am I correct?

Comment: @Thoth Sounds good to me!